# How to import address to a wallet which runs in pruned mode

Tags: bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-cash, pruning, importaddress

I am running Bitcoin Cash node with `prune=99000` mode enabled. So, I tried to import addresses of BCH from another BCH wallet by using importprivkey method and I am getting an error: `Rescan is disabled in pruned mode`.

How could I import addresses in prune mode from another wallet?

Thanks!

Comment: To import the private key, the wallet must rescan the blockchain and I think with the prune setting the import key not work because you haven't a copy of the blockchain in your local machine.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo thanks for the answer. Could I user reindex maybe on prune mode?

Comment: What does it mean, reindex the user? ps: I don't know how work the BCH but if is work how bitcoin, it not contains the user

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I am sorry there was a lint, I meant "Could I use reindex maybe on prune mode?"

Answer (score 3):

Form [bitcoin-abc](https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/679786401e1f2f286cce166a1f27a473bd9d0a7d/contrib/debian/examples/bitcoin.conf#L135) I have found this

```
# Enable pruning to reduce storage requirements by deleting old blocks. 
# This mode is incompatible with -txindex and -rescan.
# 0 = default (no pruning).
# 1 = allows manual pruning via RPC.
# >=550 = target to stay under in MiB. 
#prune=550
```

So, the command import address should call the -rescan (in Bitcoin core yes), for reconstruct the story of the private key.
So from the moment of your error message, I believe the correct answer is.

*No you cannot import a private key in prune mode*

Comment: good to know after wasting almost a week for downloading and pruning the whole blockchain